# How to redirect views using the same angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

When i am using "location.href" in order to redirect to another view my current controller reinitialize. The both views are using the same controller. What is the better way to go between views but not recreating controller?

```
   function onAddNewTest() {
            //some logic here
            location.href = '/#/testList';
    };
```

route itself:

```
    .module('applicationModule', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/testList', {
            controller: 'testController as vm',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/views/testList.html'
        })
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#url. But that will not reuse the same controller either. Just prevent the whole page to reload and the application to restart. What you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: Angular UI Router is what you're looking for, specifically multiple named views and nested routing

Comment: The main problem is that i have some array of objects in this controller, and when i am using onAddNewTest i push some new instances in this array. The problem is that i go by route than and this array starts reinitialize itself(getting some data from server side), and object which i have added recently haven't come yet.

Comment: If you want to save state shared by several controller instances, use a service. Or use your backend database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$location.path()` in your controller like this:

```
function onAddNewTest() {
    //some logic here
    $location.path('/testList');
};
```

And don't forget to add dependency to your controller.

**Hope it helps**